# oracle bpel dependent jar - loading hierachy in weblogic

Tags: java, oracle, soa, weblogic-10.x, bpel

## Environment : SOA suite 11.1.1.7

### Server : weblogic 10.x

I have a bpel composite with java embedding referring to custom libraries in a jar file.
I have the dependent jars in $project/SCA-INF/lib. With that I am packaging the composite to build a bpel suitcase.

So my question is : If I deploy my SCA jar file in the weblogic should that be suffice ?
Do I still need to include those jars in soa-ext folder ?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question... have you tried anything? Have you run into errors?

Comment: yes I tried deploying the soa composite application to weblogic. I was getting the below error :  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString                   @DisplayNameismissing

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when doing this as Weblogic will first look into it's internal JRE before looking in the deployed composites Lib folder.

The best bet is to place your jars on the servers classpath. This requires a restart.